# Data not populating in UIPickerView when field is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to learn how populate data into a UIPickerView programmatically instead of having the picker as an element on the main storyboard. I am practicing in a project so that when I get this done I can copy the code into the project I am actually trying to develop. What I have so far is when I tap on the season field, a grey picker appears at the bottom of the screen but there is no data in it. I have a feeling it is because of the way I have tried to populate the data, which I got from a tutorial on populating data into picker views, but the tutorial had a picker element on the main storyboard. Can I get some direction on this? Thank you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var enterSeason: UITextField!

var dataPickerView = UIPickerView()
var season = ["2013", "2014", "2015"] //multi-season
//var season = ["2015"] //single-season

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterSeason.inputView = dataPickerView
    //enterSeason.inputView = UIPickerView()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return season.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return season[row] as String
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var itemSelected = season[row] as String
    self.enterSeason.text  = itemSelected
}
}
```

Comment: Have you set the datasource and delegates? 

`dataPickerView.dataSource = self`
`dataPickerView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ViewController implements the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`  methods, but you need to set your ViewController as the delegate and datasource of your `UIPickerView`.

Add this code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
dataPickerView.delegate = self
dataPickerView.dataSource = self
```

and have your ViewController class declare that it conforms to the UIPickerDataSource protocol by changing

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the missing piece. I had already added the UIPickerViewDataSource to the class but needed the .delegate and .dataSource code. I am learning new stuff all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data in programmatically you need to set one more protocol: UIPickerViewDataSource.

The first line should be changed to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
```

Comment: @Audrey Thank you for your reply. I think I did what you said. I added UIPickerViewDataSource as such  `class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource`

Comment: @Audrey I still get only the grey picker with no data when I tap on the field.

Comment: @Greg My input, was only half of the puzzle. Glad it finally worked for you. Keep on learning!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you must set your class as the delegate/datasource in order to conform to the protocol methods. The same goes for UITableView, UICollectionView, and etc.

Here is it all put together:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var enterSeason: UITextField!

    var dataPickerView = UIPickerView()
    var season = ["2013", "2014", "2015"] //multi-season
    //var season = ["2015"] //single-season

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        enterSeason.inputView = dataPickerView
        dataPickerView.delegate = self
        dataPickerView.dataSource = self
        //enterSeason.inputView = UIPickerView()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return season.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return season[row] as String
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var itemSelected = season[row] as String
        self.enterSeason.text  = itemSelected
    }
    }
```